# Windows store app, horizontal scrolling when too much text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am making an app for the Windows store (xaml/c#), in this app i create a list of properties of a file. One properties is the file path, this is always too long. my solution would be to make this side scrolling when this textblock is selected.
the text would start to scroll when selected to make all the information readable. (ticker bar)

I can’t find a property to achieve this, and I find it difficult to make a custom function for this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd reconsider the idea. I had the idea many times and it was always rejected by designers. I think animating text is likely to be more annoying than clipped text. A better way might be to either wrap it in place or if you are in a list with limited item height - only show the full text after it was tapped - either with some popup or in the details view of the tapped item.

Having said that - to animate it you'd **put the `TextBlock` inside of a `Canvas`**, set the `Clip` of the `Canvas` to a `RectangleGeometry` that defines your clipping region (and update it on size updates), then animate the `Canvas.X` property of the `TextBlock`. The problem with that is that `Canvas.X` is not an "independent" property and so you'd need to set `DoubleAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation="true"` on the animation and could still get a fairly choppy animation.

A better choice might seem to be to **animate the `RenderTransform` of the `TextBlock`** (e.g. set it to a `TranslateTransform` and target the `X` property of the transform in the animation), but last time I checked - this could animate the `TextBlock` in an already clipped form, so you still wouldn't see the part of it that doesn't fit on screen. You could try that though.

**Putting the `TextBlock` in a `ScrollViewer`** might work better, but it would suffer from similar problem as the `Canvas` solution since the `ScrollViewer` doesn't even have an animatable offset property. In Windows 8.1 you get built in animations when you call `ScrollViewer.ChangeView()`, but that would likely animate too quickly. It is possible with the help of a proxy dependency property or other per-frame dependent animation as in the [`ScrollToHorizontalOffsetWithAnimation()`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/WinRTXamlToolkit.Shared/Controls/Extensions/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs) `ScrollViewer` extension method in WinRT XAML Toolkit.